# How/why does set() in {frozenset()} work?

Tags: python, hash, set, immutability

Even though sets are unhashable, membership check in other set works:

```
>>> set() in {frozenset()}
True
```

I expected `TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'`, consistent with other behaviours in Python:

```
>>> set() in {}  # doesn't work when checking in dict
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
>>> {} in {frozenset()}  # looking up some other unhashable type doesn't work
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

So, how is set membership in other set implemented?

Comment: also another error `[] in {()}` `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`

Comment: There are two questions here basically: Why can you do `set() in thingThatRequiresHashableElements`, and why is the `set()` apparently compared to the existing `frozenset()` when the membership test is actually made.

Comment: Well, it's documented: "Instances of set are compared to instances of frozenset based on their members. For example, set('abc') == frozenset('abc') returns True and so does set('abc') in set([frozenset('abc')])." - the latter case is what's going on here - but the mechanism isn't discussed there. Might be a pointer to digging in further though. https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last line of [the documentation for `set`s](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.clear) discusses this:

> Note, the `elem` argument to the [`__contains__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__contains__), [`remove()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.remove), and [`discard()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.discard)
>   methods may be a `set`. To support searching for an equivalent
>   `frozenset`, a temporary one is created from `elem`.

Answer (score 10):

`set_contains` is [implemented like this](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.0/Objects/setobject.c#L1874):

```
static int
set_contains(PySetObject *so, PyObject *key)
{
    PyObject *tmpkey;
    int rv;

    rv = set_contains_key(so, key);
    if (rv < 0) {
        if (!PySet_Check(key) || !PyErr_ExceptionMatches(PyExc_TypeError))
            return -1;
        PyErr_Clear();
        tmpkey = make_new_set(&PyFrozenSet_Type, key);
        if (tmpkey == NULL)
            return -1;
        rv = set_contains_key(so, tmpkey);
        Py_DECREF(tmpkey);
    }
    return rv;
}
```

So this will delegate directly to [`set_contains_key`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.0/Objects/setobject.c#L430) which will essentially hash the object and then look up the element using its hash.

If the object is unhashable, `set_contains_key` returns `-1`, so we get inside that `if`. Here, we check *explicitly* whether the passed `key` object is a set (or an instance of a set subtype) **and** whether we previously got a type error. This would suggest that we tried a containment check with a `set` but that failed because it is unhashable.

In that exact situation, we now create a new `frozenset` from that `set` and attempt the containment check using `set_contains_key` again. And since frozensets are properly hashable, we are able to find our result that way.

This explains why the following examples will work properly even though the set itself is not hashable:

```
>>> set() in {frozenset()}
True
>>> set(('a')) in { frozenset(('a')) }
True
```